# PDF for random variable constrained by other random variables

Tags: predictive-models, density-function, constraint

I'm very novice with prob and stats so maybe my title is incorrect.

What I'm trying to do is predict when a set of events will happen in the future.  For each event I have a probability model of when it's likely to occur independent of all other events.  However some events are going to be constrained by other events.

Given event *A* and *B* each with a duration and a random variable representing it's start time they may have these types of constraints:

- *A* must end before *B* begins
- *A* and *B* must not overlap at all
- A must start after *B* starts and end before *B* ends (*B* contains *A*)

I have an idea of how I would do this if I assume A happens first then *B* happens.    I think you would do something like a double integral on `pdf(A) * pdf(B)` where the constraints are placed in the intervals of integration. However this will only output *B*'s new pdf but I also need the effect on *A*.  *A* affects *B* and *B* affects *A*.  As if they are placed simultaneously not sequentially.  And of course it's not just *A* and *B* but *n* events.

Even if you don't have an answer, helping me with describing the problem better or learning the terms I need to know in order to search for the answer would be very helpful.

Comment: Seems like you mean conditional probability, aren't you?

Comment: I think you mean `pdf(A)+pdf(B)` don't you? One, then the other?

Comment: Yeah, conditional probability sounds right as a name for the integral thing I was talking about.  But I don't think that solves my problem.  So say A' = P(A|B).  Now how do I get B'.  Is it B' = P(B|A} or is it P(B|A'). And then should I adjust A with B'.  Do I go on iteratively?